# Advertencia en constraints xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Tengo un Boton y dos View dentro de una tabla (UITableView) todo esta correcto en todo los tamaños de dispositivos excepto que cuando cambio de tamaño de dispositivo me muestra una advertencia de **"Misplaced View"** al darle clic en el botón de ACTUALIZAR FRAMES desaparece, pero cambio de tamaño de dispositivo, vuelve.

Es solo una advertencia para actualizar los frames o estoy frente a un error.

Agradezco me pudieran aclarar ese tema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente es un aviso para que sepas que no se va a ver exactamente como lo tienes en el storyboard.

Al darle a ese botón, Xcode recalcula el tamaño de las vistas adaptándolo al nuevo dispositivo seleccionado.

Dicho de otro modo, no es un warning que luego te vaya a causar problemas. Tu autolayout está bien configurado, y al arrancar la aplicación el layout será calculado en base a las constraints que has añadido, para cada dispositivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaracion...